# Is it possible that newer data is overwritten by old after MySQL replication slowdown?

Tags: mysql, replication

I've set up master-master replication of 2 servers and in one of the tables I use `REPLACE INTO` to update the data in a table. Is it possible that a link between the 2 servers goes down, then server 1 updates a certain row, a few seconds later the server 2 updates the same row and when the two get connected back, the more up-to-data on server 2 is overwritten by the data from server 1?

Answer (score 1):

You've just discovered why master-master "replication" setups with MySQL are not so much of a great idea. Worse yet, your changed data from server 2 is propagated to server 1 as well, so they will end up with different (swapped) data within the two replicas of your tables for good and never know about it. Except in the case where you are altering one of the columns you filter your query by, where replication will break (stop with an error) due to differencies in column count affected by the query (which is recorded and checked for by the MySQL replicator implementation).

You should use [MySQL cluster](http://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/faq.html#1) if you want to pursue this kind of setup with MySQL - it has [means to resolve this kind of conflicts coherently](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-cluster-replication-conflict-resolution.html). In contrast to "free" MySQL setups, licensing is going to cost you $$$.

Comment: Thanks, I've actually tried that setup and can confirm that the changes got swapped in the end.